# Hyponatremia and hypobicarbonatemia

Tags: diabetes, carbon-monoxide-poisoning, hyponatremia

What is the answer to the following question? And why?

An untreated patient with which one of the following conditions is MOST LIKELY to present with (relative to a healthy individual) decreased plasma bicarbonate and decreased total body sodium?

- (a) diabetic ketoacidosis
- (b) carbon monoxide poisoning
- (c) anaphylactic shock
- (d) severe iron-deficiency anaemia
- (e) a panic attack and hyperventilation

Comment: Is this homework?  And what steps have you taken to answer this yourself?

Comment: We have a similar rule like Biology that homework questions are off topic.  If this is an MCAT question or something that you're looking for clarification on, please specify that.

Answer (score 4):

> **Carbonic Acid / Bicarbonate Buffer System**

### CO2 + H2O ↔ H2CO3 ↔ H+ + HCO3

---

***Metabolic Acidosis and DKA***

---

*Includes the following:*

- Decreased pH
- Low HCO3 levels
- This condition occurs when acids other than carbonic acid accumulate in ECF or when there is a loss of HCO3.
- Rarely occurs spontaneously but in is with other problems
  *(starvation, shock, trauma... but the answer you're looking for is*.......

---

### ANSWER

[**Diabetic Ketoacidosis (DKA)**](http://www.webmd.com/diabetes/tc/diabetic-ketoacidosis-dka-topic-overview#1)

---

> **Key Points** *(Information Below MerekManual Professional Version)*

---

- Metabolic acidosis can be caused by acid accumulation due to
  increased acid production or acid ingestion; decreased acid
  excretion; or GI or renal HCO3− loss.
- Metabolic acidoses are categorized based on whether the anion gap is
  high or normal.
- High anion gap acidoses are most often due to ketoacidosis, lactic
  acidosis, renal failure, or certain toxic ingestions
- Normal anion gap acidoses are most often due to GI or renal HCO3−
  loss
- Calculate delta gap to identify concomitant metabolic alkalosis, and
  apply Winters formula to see whether respiratory compensation is
  appropriate or reflects a 2nd acid-base disorder.
- Treat the underlying cause
- NaHCO3 is indicated when acidosis is due to a change in HCO3− (normal
  anion gap acidosis)
- Intravenous NaHCO3 is controversial in high anion gap acidosis (but
  may be considered when pH < 7.00, with a target pH of ≤ 7.10).

---

***Sources:***

http://www.webmd.com/diabetes/tc/diabetic-ketoacidosis-dka-topic-overview#1

http://www.merckmanuals.com/professional/endocrine-and-metabolic-disorders/acid-base-regulation-and-disorders/metabolic-acidosis